# Mercurial, change branch of changeset

Tags: mercurial, branch

I have 2 branches in my Mercurial repository. '**default**' and '**other**'

**default** branch A - B - C - D

**other**   branch E - F

I need to move B changeset to other branch. 
So it will look like this:

**default** branch A - C - D

**other**   branch E - F - B

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Graft-based solution**

- Graft (`hg help graft`) B to target branch
- Remove (histed extension) B from source branch (graft only make copy of changeset, without removing original)

**Rebase-based solution**

- Rebase B to `other` branch
- Because rebase move also descendants of rebased changeset -  rebase C back to `default`

Answer (score 1):

The following solution doesn't require enabling any extensions.  It does assume the existence of the `patch` utility, though.

On **default**:

```
$ hg diff -c B > diff.out
$ hg backout --merge -r B
$ hg merge
$ hg ci
```

On **other** branch:

```
$ patch -p1 < diff.out
$ hg ci
```

Comment: Huge thank you for solution, I still receive such message abort: nothing to merge, (use 'hg update' instead) in your solution. But I understood how to fix it. It was what I really needed. ++ to you.

Comment: Better (and *more natural* way and slightly more Mercurial's way) will be `hg export` + `hg import` in your model. And, BTW, without stripping original, you made copy of, not move, changeset